# Merge the dateformat, date-format, and date-formatting tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

There are three tags with a very similar meaning:

- [dateformat](/questions/tagged/dateformat) (310 questions)
- [date-format](/questions/tagged/date-format) (56 questions)
- [date-formatting](/questions/tagged/date-formatting) (75 questions)

They should be probably merged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateFormat` can refer to one of the following:

- The [`DateFormat` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateformat.aspx) in [the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.aspx)
- The [`DateFormat` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) in Java

And possibly more.

I dislike tags that are this specific to the API level, and the questions in the [dateformat](/questions/tagged/dateformat) tag, while probably referring to one of the two APIs above, still are about formatting dates.

I'd recommend that the canonical tag be [date-formatting](/questions/tagged/date-formatting) which will refer to the process of formatting dates.  The [date-format](/questions/tagged/date-format) tag should be merged into the [date-formatting](/questions/tagged/date-formatting) tag.

I'd be cautious about doing anything with the [dateformat](/questions/tagged/dateformat) tag; there are other date-format-specific tags in the system, and while I'm not eager to get rid of them, there could be people that are searching on [visual-basic](/questions/tagged/visual-basic) and [dateformat](/questions/tagged/dateformat) or [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [dateformat](/questions/tagged/dateformat).  However, I still approve of merging the [dateformat](/questions/tagged/dateformat) tag into the [date-formatting](/questions/tagged/date-formatting) tag.

We'll do a merge of all the tags if there's no major objections.